# Changing colors in stacked barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I need the three colors for this bar plot to be specific colors. 
RET should be "chartreuse3",
FiR/FG should be aquamarine4,
RHA should be "goldenrod1".

I have found some solutions to this issue but when I attempt to implement, it doesn't work.

```
fall3 <- structure(list(Community = c("First-Year", "First-Year", "First-Year", 
"First-Year", "Upper-Class", "Upper-Class", "First-Year", "First-Year", 
"Upper-Class", "Upper-Class"), Division = c("FiR/FG", "RHA", 
"RHA", "RET", "FiR/FG", "RET", "RET", "RHA", "RHA", 
"FiR/FG"), Count = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



gg_color_hue <- function(n) {
  hues = seq(15, 375, length=n+1)
  hcl(h=hues, l=65, c=100)[1:n]
}

#make custom palette

mycols <- gg_color_hue(length(unique(fall3$Division)))
names(mycols) <- unique(fall3$Division)
mycols["RET"] <- 'sienna'
mycols["FiR/FG"] <- 'darkgoldenrod1'
mycols["RHA"] <- 'darkolivegreen3'


stick <- ggplot(fall3, aes(Community))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Division))+
 scale_color_manual(values=mycols)
```

I hope to have a bar chart with the appropriate colors. Additionally, something is telling me I am doing this wrong. Because my chart says there is an equal amount of events in first-year and upper-class, which is not the case.

Comment: Change `scale_color_manual` to `scale_fill_manual`

Comment: @sumshyftw did not work.

Comment: Another thing to note here is that the `gg_color_hue` function call is not doing anything since you go on to manually replace the color values it generates with different color names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mycols<- c("RET" = "sienna", "FiR/FG" = "darkgoldenrod1", "RHA" = "darkolivegreen3")
ggplot(fall3, aes(Community, fill = Division))+
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=mycols)
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, I used the colors from your code, which were in conflict with the first line of the question. Adjust to taste.